# How many permutations for 500 sentences

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have 500 individual sentences. I'm wondering how many unique story combinations can be made using all 500. The sentences can be placed in any order. This seems like a fairly easy thing to work out but I have no idea where to begin. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

thanks.

Edited 15/09/17:

Instead of sentences say they are individual numbers 1 to 500 all in order from 1 - 500. That's 1 permutation.  Number 1 can then move to position 2. That's another permutation.  Number 1 then moves to every position until getting to position 500. So 500 permutions just by moving number 1. You can then move number 2 to position 3, 4, 5, etc. Then the same for all others numbers. And then we can move blocks together, 1 and 2 together through the sequence. Seems to me that there are far more than 500  combinations. So How many permutions are there using all 500 sentences

Comment: how many orders of 500 things are there  maybe that will help if not maybe try how many orders of 3 things there are.

Comment: If the sentences don't have to make sense, then the number of ways to arrange them should be the same as the number of ways to arrange $500$ distinct objects, which is $$500!$$ (see [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial))

Comment: It can't be 500 surely. Instead of sentences say they are individual numbers 1 to 500 all in order from 1 - 500. That's 1 permutation.  Number 1 can then move to position 2. That's another permutation.  Number 1 then moves to every position until getting to position 500. So 500 permutions just by moving number 1. You can then move number 2 to position 3, 4, 5, etc. Then the same for all others numbers. And then we can move blocks together, 1 and 2 together through the sequence. Seems to me that there are far more than 500  combinations. So How many permutions are there using all 500 sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your story will end up containing a total of $500$ sentences total, since you have $500$ sentences all of which you want to use.

For the first sentence of your story, there are a total of $500$ possible sentences that you could use. Thus, for the second sentence, there are $499$ possible sentences to use, since you already chose one for the first sentence. And for the third, there are $498$ possible sentences, and so on. Thus the number of possible stories is
$$500\cdot 499\cdot 498\cdot 497\cdot ...\cdot2\cdot 1=500!$$
Does this answer your question?

Comment: and the reason we use 500! as the symbol is because it's over 1100 digits long, which means it's about 550 characters too long for a comment.

Comment: It can't be 500 surely. Instead of sentences say they are individual numbers 1 to 500 all in order from 1 - 500. That's 1 permutation.  Number 1 can then move to position 2. That's another permutation.  Number 1 then moves to every position until getting to position 500. So 500 permutions just by moving number 1. You can then move number 2 to position 3, 4, 5, etc. Then the same for all others numbers. And then we can move blocks together, 1 and 2 together through the sequence. Seems to me that there are far more than 500  combinations. So How many permutions are there using all 500 sentences

Comment: @user1022772 I didn't say it was $500$ - I said that there would be $500!$ stories. Are you familiar with factorial notation?

Comment: No I wasn't. thanks for the help. Very much appreciated

Comment: @user1022772 No problem, I'm glad to help! :)